# Parse method not handling formatting correctly

Tags: java, oop, datetime

My code is supposed to print out the difference between the entered date and now. Then the output will be formatted according to the ISO LocalDate format.

Parse method not handling formatting correctly.

```
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.*;

//Main class
public class TimeBetween{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String dateFormat = "MMMM d, yyyy";
    LocalDate aDate = null;
    boolean validStr = false;

 //parse method not handling formatting correctly.
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(validStr==false){
        System.out.print("Enter a date: ");
//Try and catch 
        try {
            String dateEntered = br.readLine();
            aDate = LocalDate.parse(dateEntered,formatter);
            validStr = true;
        }catch(IOException | DateTimeParseException ex){
            validStr = false;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Date entered was: "+aDate);
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); 

    Period between;
    if(aDate.isBefore(now)){
        between = Period.between(aDate,now);
    }else{
        between = Period.between(now,aDate);
    }

    int years = between.getYears();
    int months = between.getMonths();
    int days =  between.getDays();

//Printing out year month and day differences
    System.out.println("There are"    +years+"years"+months+"months"+days+"days");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you will please specify precisely what you want your code to do (with an example) and how observed behaviour differs, we’d love to help you. Thank you. PS The `parse` method is not supposed to do any formatting. That’s what we have the `format` method for.

Comment: Thank you for your kind respond. The code is supposed to print out the diff between the entered date and now. Then the output will be formatted according to the ISO LocalDate format.

Comment: I set my locale to Irish English and entered `February 27, 1999`. Your program printed `Date entered was: 1999-02-27`, which agrees with ISO local date format. And then `There are19years7months19days`, which I believe is correct (though spaces may help readability). Is everything fine?

Comment: Tips: (1) Give your formatter explicit locale, for example `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat, Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IE"))`. (2) Most programmers prefer the “not” operator to comparing with `false`, for example `while (!validStr)`.

Comment: (3) The input format you are asking for seems to agree with American date format, so you may also use `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(Locale.US);`. It’s often preferable to avoid mingling with specifying a format pattern string if you can.

Comment: You are the best Ole V.V! I was entering the month in upper case. FEBRUARY 27, 1999. Forgive my ignorance. I take MMMM in the string to mean it must be in upper case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Enter month in the case used in your locale

As your program stands in the question the user is required to enter the month in the expected case, for example uppercase `F` and lowercase `ebruary` for February. (Edit:) Pattern letter uppercase `M` is used for month while lowercase `m` means minutes. Therefore the `M`s in the format pattern string have to be in uppercase even though you are not supposed to type the month that way, and it also isn’t formatted in uppercase if you format a date back into a string.

Tip: When parsing using a formatter won’t work, try formatting a value with the same formatter to see what it expects your input string to look like. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat, Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IE"));
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Dublin")).format(formatter));
```

Example output:

> October 17, 2018

Here you can see that the month is not in uppercase.

Tip 2: give explicit locale for your formatter so you know it will also work as expected on computers with a different default locale and if some day you happen to play with the locale setting of your own computer.

### To accept month in uppercase

I don’t think it was what you wanted, but for the sake of completeness: To allow the month to be entered in all uppercase letters use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `parseCaseInsensitive`method like this:

```java
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern(dateFormat)
            .toFormatter(Locale.forLanguageTag("en-IE"));
```

With this change here’s a sample session:

```
Enter a date: FEBRUARY 27, 1999
Date entered was: 1999-02-27
There are19years7months19days
```

The date is output in ISO 8601 format for a calendar date. And I believe the calculation of the period is correct.

### Link

[`DateTimeFormatter` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) where you can see the uppercase and lowercase pattern letters and study the difference between `m` and `M`, `d` and `D` and `y` and `Y`.

Comment: Thank you Ole V.V !